# How to determine font used in dialog window

Tags: windows, fonts, dialog, window, analysis

How to determine font used for some control in some dialog window in runnning process on Windows? Something like Microsoft Spy++ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find this functionality in Spy++, but here's a small program that I just wrote for this task:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: findfont WINDOWTITLE\n");
        return 1;
    }
    LPCSTR title = argv[1];
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, title);
    if (hWnd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Window titled \"%s\" not found\n", title);
        return 1;
    }
    HFONT hFont = (HFONT) SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
    if (hFont == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WM_GETFONT failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    LOGFONT lf = { 0 };
    if (!GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GetObject failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Face name: %s Height: %ld\n", lf.lfFaceName, lf.lfHeight);
    return 0;
}
```